# "riechen" vs. "riechen an"

Tags: standard-german

What's the difference between "riechen" and "riechen an"? The wikipedia article describes them as almost synonymous.

https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/riechen

Comment: I don't see, what [Duden](https://www.duden.de/rechtschreibung/riechen) or [DWDS](https://www.dwds.de/wb/riechen) leave open.

Comment: @guidot: I can see it. Duden and DWDS do not explicitely rectify an error in the [english Wiktionary article about the German verb *reichen*](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/riechen) which is confusing everybody who tries to learn from the wrong resources.

Comment: Da fällt mir ein: "Solang die Füsse riechen und die Nase läuft, bleibt Deutsch eine ziemlich schwierige Sprache"

Comment: @HubertSchölnast   I start believing that there should be a rule for users here that looking up things only in Wikipedia (or Wiktionary) is not considered sufficient own research to qualify for a question. Even if somebody does not have access to physical books and libraries, there are enough online resources that can be used. People start getting very lazy. Or worse: they start getting unaware of resources except Wikipedia... which is a big problem perhaps not for meanings of words, but there are topics of societal relevance where content is heavily biased through interested parties.

Comment: @Christian: it is probably not laziness, but indeed unawareness. I didn't know most of these resources either. I learned about them from the the answers and comments here.

Comment: @ChristianGeiselmann: Since when doesn't count asking question as own research? All the resources you name do not qualify as Q&A resources (I like them all, don't get me wrong, but own research is own research and judging too early is just inappropriate for Q&A esp. for languages). But by rule there is no single answer even. You think OP was lazy asking? Probably, but why not ask directly?

Answer (score 6):

1. Do not use English Wiktionary to get informed about German words. Use [German Wiktionary](https://de.wiktionary.org/wiki/riechen) instead. In [English Wiktionary](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/riechen) you find this sentence which is grammatically wrong:

   > wrong: Ich rieche an (+ Akk) dein Parfüm.

   The correct form is:

   > Ich rieche an (+ Dat).

   But the dative object is not a fragrant. It is something that emits an odor. You can say:

   > Ich rieche an deinem Parfümfläschchen.
   >   I smell (on) your perfume bottle.

   If you want to say, that you smell the parfume, you can do it this way:

   > Ich rieche dein Parfüm.
   >   I smell your perfume.
2. You can use German *riechen* exactly the same way as English *to smell*.

The verb *riechen* (*to smell*) can mean:

- to emanate fragrance

  > Rosen riechen besser als getragene Socken.
  >   Roses smell better than worn socks.
- to perceive smell

  > Hunde riechen besser als Menschen.
  >   Dogs smell better than humans.

And it can be used together with various prepositions:

- > Du riechst nach Rauch.
  >   You smell like smoke.
- > Heinz riecht an der Rose.
  >   Heinz smells (on) the rose.

Comment: Actually, you *can* say "I rieche an deinem Parfüm", but then "Parfüm" is to be understood as "Parfümfläschchen".

Comment: @Uwe  ... which is a good example for the rhetoric figure of metonymy. If you need one.

Comment: Your English examples "Heinz smells on the rose" and "I smell on your perfume bottle" are both wrong. You could possibly say "Heinz gives the rose (or perfume bottle) a sniff".

Comment: @fdb: Your reputation is sufficient to edit answers and questions of other people to correct such errors.

Answer (score 4):

Riechen is the general verb for to smell, while riechen an means to smell sth.

Example sentences:

- Die Blumen riechen frisch. - The flowers smell fresh.
- an den Blumen riechen - to smell the flowers
- Sie riecht an den Blumen. - She smells the flowers.
- Sie riecht nach Blumen. - She smells like flowers.

Comment: I'd suggest that anriechen is more of "smelling/sniffing at" something. Here you make it sound like "Sie riecht die Blumen" isn't a valid translation of "She smells the flowers".

Answer (score 2):

Well... it's the same "riechen", however the preposition "an" always requires accusative or dative. In conjunction with "riechen" it's always dative:

> Ich rieche an den Blumen.

The sentence

> Ich rieche die Blumen.

is without "an" and has accusative, but you can construct sentences without:

> Die Blumen riechen gut.

BTW, the Wikipedia example

> Ich rieche an (+ Akk) dein Parfüm.
>   I smell your perfume.

is IMHO wrong or at least misleading. Either you would have to say

> Ich rieche an dein**em** (dative) Parfüm.

or

> Ich rieche an **dir** (dative) dein Parfüm.

or - really bad if the spouse says it to her husband:

> Ich rieche an dir ihr Parfüm.

;-)

But obviously you can't use

> Ich rieche an dein Parfüm.

and

> Ich rieche dein Parfüm.

synonymously. The first sentence is simply wrong.
"riechen an" simply is - and requires - different grammar.

Comment: Is there actually a sentence where riechen an requires akk.? I think your first sentence might be misleading. Maybe you should clarify, or provide me with a counter example :)

Comment: @infinitezero You are right, it was a bit confusing :-) However, in some dialects accusative is used. Where I come from, saying/hearing "Ich riech' an die Blumma" is absolutely fine ;-)

Comment: In what region is this used? Just so I can avoid it.

Comment: @infinitezero It's quite common in Bavaria, especially Frankonia. I don't know if it's used somewhere else.

Answer (score 1):

> What's the difference between "riechen" and "riechen an"?

German language is quite straight forward and then hunts you on the specifics.

First of all "riechen" covers all of the subset of "riechen an", which is just less generic.

So as you have asked for the difference I really prevented to answer your question so far.

So most common the difference is the addition of (DE:)"an".

this little two letter addition actually adds direction and localisation (for the verb "riechen"). e.g. something smells and you're just smelling it but you do not give any localization (of the smell) - this is without (DE:)"an".

But if you smell on/onto/of (and you name of what that) something (excuse my bad English), you actually denote what you smell *where* exactly.

And to make this even more concrete. Consider "that" something is a special person or even a special body part. Or a flower or a special flower part. Inhale it. So you smell something very specific because you put your nose close to it. That is "riechen an", you put your nose next to it, mostly normally very close, and inhale. Go for it, it's a pleasure (or at least should be).

Otherwise, even Germans are perhaps not that polite, but even then, they don't say where they have put their nose and then BAD BAD BAD smell, they just say they smelled something ((DE:)"riechen") out of thin air, and they don't tell you where exactly they put their nose (DE:)"riechen an".

I hope this translates well.

Answer (score 0):

Be careful with "Hunde riechen besser als Menschen." It means both - that they smell better and that they can smell better.